# how to bind an image from database to image control in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to bind a image in image control from javascript ,the image is stored in the image datatype format, in the database.
I want to retrieve name,age,image,adrress from database and assign name ,age ,adress to the textbox and assign image to the image control through javascript,when user click on Show Info Button.

How to do this,can handler.ashx can be useful,how do i get name,age,image,address from handler page.??
How to bind image to image control from javascript??

Comment: could you elaborate more and show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post what have you tried . When you say using javascript are you aready making an ajax call and retriving this infromation ? You done need to get other data than image from ashx.

If you have image id you will need to make ashx to get image .

```
function GetImage(id) {

            document.getElementById("UserImage").src="Handler.ashx?id=" + id;

    }
```

Comment: $('#imgAssetCard').load('GetImageHandler.ashx?Invid=' + val + '', function () {
                          alert('Load was performed.');
                      });